# how to show selected in f.select in rails4 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Hi I am having this in my view

```
<%= f.select :role,:collection => Employee.roles.keys%>
```

I want to show selected in this i.e @employee[:role]. When I give this

```
<%= f.select :role,:collection => Employee.roles.keys, :selected => @employee[:role] %>
```

then i get this type of list

```
<select id="employee_role" name="employee[role]">
      <optgroup label="collection">
        <option value="super_admin">super_admin</option>
        <option value="hr">hr</option>
        <option value="admin">admin</option>
        <option value="inventory">inventory</option>
        <option value="employee">employee</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="selected">HR</optgroup>
 </select>
```

I don't know how to show my selected value. Please guide in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you please show what are you getting in `@employee`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this following code.

```
<%= f.select :role,Employee.roles.keys, :selected => @employee[:role] %>
```